# Calculations with NULL value

Tags: sql, aggregation

I am trying to calculate the difference between two columns, but sometimes one of the columns has NULL value and SQL is ignoring that.

Right now I am using this:
        if("source indicator"  = 'Total OPEX', ("Eur Amount" -"EUR Target") * -1, "Eur Amount" -"EUR Target") as "Diff."

Is there any other way to calculate this (please note that OPEX value) and get the expected results?

Thanks

Comment: Which db engine are you using?

Comment: `if` is non standard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `case` and `coalesce()`:

```
(case when "source indicator" = 'Total OPEX'
      then coalesce("Eur Amount", 0) - coalesce("EUR Target", 0) * -1
      else coalesce("Eur Amount", 0) - coalesce("EUR Target", 0)
 end)
```

The advantage of `case` is that it is ANSI-standard SQL, supported by pretty much all databases.  `if()` is database-dependent.